# elasticsearch - why are all shards of an index allocated on one node?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Elasticsearch Version: 6.5.4

There are 16 nodes in my cluster and the index has 10 shards.

There is a new index created everyday.

It works well for several months.

But a strange thing happen today. 10 shards of the new index are allocated to on node.

[image]

I'm sure all nodes are working well. None node or procession restarting.

How can this happen?

Comment: What is the value for number of replica? What % of disk space is free on other 15 nodes?

Comment: @Opster ES Ninja Nishant  Thank you for your attention. Replica num is 0 and disk space is enough (usage < 50%)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution using index setting `index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/allocation-total-shards.html#allocation-total-shards